# How to detect redirection in Django view

Tags: python, django, http-redirect

I have a view that returns a redirection.

```
return redirect(reverse('my-view-name'))
```

Is it a way to detect redirection inside a view method?

I've searched in `request` object attributes but couldn't find any one that indicates redirection.

Comment: You inspect the response object, that is what you here return: a response object with a `302` status code.

Comment: Where are you trying to detect the redirection? In `my-view-name` that you redirect to? And what do you want to do when you detect the redirect?

Answer (score 1):

A redirection simply means you return a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) with status code `302` and a header `Location` that contains the location to which you redirect. There is nothing special about that response, and the target view is not triggered by the redirect response itself.

The browser that receives such response, can then thus act by visiting that link, and then it will thus trigger the view to which you redirected. But a browser does not per se does that (you can usually alter some settings to let your browser (not) follow such redirects).

You can thus for example [implement your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that does something with such redirect:

```
def redirect_processing_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if 300 <= response.status_code < 400:
            # the response is a redirect
            # ...
            pass

    return middleware
```

An alternative is to add a watchdog on the `redirect(..)` call, but that can be circumvented, by simply creating a `HttpResponse` for example, and manually alter that response to transform it into a redirect response.

You can do some static code analyses (automatically or manually). But due to the dynamic nature of Python, it is impossible to know for sure what views will trigger redirections: one can obfuscate the `redirect` call, by using a proxy function, etc., or dynamically alter/monkey patch code such that redirections are taking place without (explicitly) calling `redirect(..)`.